# WPF DataGrid column header sort arrow disappear after changing the source of its view collection source

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, collectionviewsource

I have the following simple code that I can reproduce this problem:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source.View}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                            Binding="{Binding Name}"
                            SortMemberPath="Name"
                            SortDirection="Ascending"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

View Model:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Data> _collection1 = new ObservableCollection<Data> {new Data("item 1"), new Data("item 2")};
private readonly ObservableCollection<Data> _collection2 = new ObservableCollection<Data> {new Data("person 1"), new Data("person 2")};

public MainViewModel()
{
    Source.Source = _collection1;

    // Set up a timer that runs 5 seconds.
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ObserveOn(AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext).Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        // Get existing sort descriptions.
        var existingSortDescription = Source.View.SortDescriptions.ToList();

        // Change source.
        Source.Source = _collection2;

        // This has to be done in order to maintain the sort order.
        existingSortDescription.ForEach(Source.SortDescriptions.Add);
    });
}

public CollectionViewSource Source { get; } = new CollectionViewSource();

private class Data
{
    public Data(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

So what the above code does is, that when the app starts, use `_collection1` as the source of the items source of the data grid to begin with.

After 5 seconds, change the items source of the data grid to `_collection2`.

If you run the above code, the sort direction arrow in the "Name" column header will disappear as soon as the source is changed to `_collection2`, but the sorting is still correct.

Is this a bug in WPF `DataGrid` control or I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SortDescriptions` that you add to the `View` of the `CollectionViewSource` in the view model doesn't affect the arrows that you see in the `DataGrid` control in the view.

You can programmatically display the arrow for a specific column by setting its `SortDirection` property. So what you could do is to create a custom `DataGrid` control that handles this for you (the built-one doesn't as you have already discovered), e.g.:

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        INotifyCollectionChanged oldView = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (oldView != null)
            oldView.CollectionChanged -= View_CollectionChanged;

        INotifyCollectionChanged newView = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (newView != null)
            newView.CollectionChanged += View_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void View_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ICollectionView view = sender as ICollectionView;
        if (view != null)
        {
            SortDescription sd = view.SortDescriptions.LastOrDefault();
            if (sd != null)
            {
                DataGridColumn column = Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SortMemberPath == sd.PropertyName);
                if (column != null)
                {
                    column.SortDirection = sd.Direction;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You then simply replace your `<DataGrid />` elements with `<local:CustomDataGrid />` elements in your XAML.

Comment: I think, here we also need to reset the sort directions for all other columns.